# CQL query on 'validFrom/validTo timestamps'

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm currently trying to model a column family that has two timestamps specifying whether an entry is valid (or 'active') at a given date (typically execution time).

No big issue with traditional SQL, 64 gigs of RAM and some indices, we're doing that quite often with our SQL server.

However, in CQL I haven't managed to model this scenario and write valid queries for it.

My basic model is (**I skipped the PK definition!**)

```
create table myTable(
    id uuid,
    validFrom timeuuid,
    validTo timeuuid,
    someInformationalData varChar
);
```

Some explanations:

- due to the fact, that a validity date is not unique, I need a combined key in my final application this is going to be a usergroup reference (would be an ideal partition key)
- validFrom/To are designed to be optional, but I could deal with by using boundary values (1970, 2038) for 'null' values passed through the persistence layer

I tried various combinations of partitioning/clustering keys, however neither of them resulted in valid CQL

```
-- only active results
select * 
from
     myTable
where
     validFrom < now()
and
     validTo > now()
```

I'm quite new to the NoSQL/CQL world and am struggling a bit with converting some of our applications. I could do it in memory, but I'm afraid, this could get a bottleneck at some point...

No sure if this kind of 'I have no idea what I'm doing' yell is appropriate, but any kind of help would be appreciated. :)

***edit* Here's one of the approaches I've been messing around with**

```
drop table if exists myTable;

create table myTable(
    id int,
    datefrom timeuuid,
    dateto timeuuid,
    someColumns varChar,
    primary key((id,datefrom),dateto)
 );

create index if not exists my_idx on myTable(datefrom); 

insert into myTable(id, datefrom,dateto,somecolumns)
values(0,minTimeuuid('1970-01-01 00:00:00'),minTimeuuid('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),'test');
insert into myTable(id,datefrom,dateto,somecolumns)
values(1,minTimeuuid('1970-01-01 00:00:00'),minTimeuuid('2012-01-01 00:00:00'),'test2');


select * from myTable where dateto > now() allow filtering;
-- invalid ("A column of a partition key can be restricted only if the preceding one is restricted by an Equal relation.")
select * from myTable where datefrom < now() and dateto > now()  allow filtering;
```

The first query is limiting my result, the row with 'validTo=2012-01-01' is filtered, but I wasn't able to work out a scheme that worked on both limitations in the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, what you are looking for is a way to run a range query based on the timestamp. Basically to be able to do this, your model will have to have the timestamp component as part of the clustering key:

```
create table myTable(
  eventType uuid,
  ts timestamp,
  val text,
  PRIMARY KEY (eventType, ts)
);
```

The above will allow you to run a query like: `SELECT eventType, val from myTable where eventType = 'your_event' and ts >= 'start_ts' and ts < 'end_ts'`.

What you need to remember is that the clustering keys are dictating the order on disk, thus making it possible to run efficiently queries like above. You can read more details about this in the [CQL spec SELECT section](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#selectStmt).

Comment: You almost got it... but my scheme has [two] timestamps compared against current date -> it has to be 'in range' to identify valid entries.

However, it doesn't work because there are some limitations on queries like that -> you need at least an 'equals' statement in the where clause. 

I totally understand that this harms some NoSQL principles, if it would work as expected, there could be lots of harmful table scans, especially when data is cluttered on multiple nodes.

I'm not expecting millions of entries, but maybe I find another approach which suits CQL better.

Comment: @DoNuT I probably don't have the whole picture of your app, but the model above would not require start and end timestamps. In its current form it's a wide-row (the old terms) and you could easily record multiple values in this row. To give you an example of what I'm thinking: you could insert a event_type = 'start' when the value becomes valid and then event_type = 'end' when the value is invalidated. (while writing the previous sentence I was also wondering if something like TTLs could be used in your case)

Comment: The idea is to have a history of a 'price' as well as the possibility of creating entries that will be valid in the future. For example a price that's valid from March 1-3,3-7,10-17, ... - you just populate the lookup table, the valid entry is determined at runtime (based on current date). Vice versa you could also grab historic values for reporting and analysis. Does that make sense? ;) However... I think, I'll have to re-model this entity, maybe having a 'start' and 'end' entry as proposed by you - easy query, aggregation done in business logic and we're done... :D

Answer (score 0):

Their is no such thing as Now() in cassandra like any other sql databases. you have to clearly mention today's date instead of Now() ..

You can use columns in which you defined as primary key or secondary index in where clause.

Comment: IHMO think 'now' is OK for timeuuid columns. However, this is working with a single timestamp.

I forgot to mention that I skipped the PK definition because I found no valid approach.

Comment: I've added a full-grown sample to state this issue - either way, I was running into one of the CQL limitations, e.g. only restriction using equals, ...

For the first months of operation I'm probably fine with doing a post-result filtering in memory, but on the long run it would be great to achieve this on server side.

Maybe my model is c**p, but thats how the data should be evaluated...